Rav Chaim Palagi and the 50th level of impurity in the haggadah
Rav Daniel Glatstein shlita says in a recent interview with ArtScroll (min. 23:24) that Rav Chaim Palagi, in his sefer Zechira Le'Chaim (Chaim Le Rosh, Haggadah Shel Pesach) divides the sections of the haggadah 50 times (Rav Chaim Palagi wrote it as "piska 1, piska 2 etc..), corresponding to the 50th level of impurity, Bnei Yisroel would have sunken into, if they remained any longer in Mitzrayim.
Rav Chaim Palagi is quoted and it is explained that he quotes Rabbi Eliyahu HaKohen of Izmir (The Shevet Mussar) in saying that the words "Yetzias Mitzrayim" appears 50 times in the Chumash. Rav Glatstein in his sefer on Pesach mentions the מדרש תלפיות
(Midrash Talpiyos), but also there I could not find any reference to it.

Does anyone know where Rav Chaim Palagi quotes the Shevet Mussar and what his source from the Shevet Mussar is, where this whole concept is explained that would explain that piska 1-50 refer to the 50 levels of tumah, and the 50 times Yetzias Mitzrayim is mentioned in the Chumash.
Edit: Rav Glatstein quotes from חיים לראש סוף מגיד (so Magid in the Haggadah Shel Pesach Chaim LeRosh). Where can this be found, in a clear typesetting?
